# Laravel casting not working on double and decimal setting to zeros

Tags: laravel

I have 2 `decimal(10,8)` fields on mysql with this migration:

```
$table->decimal('lat', 10, 8)->nullable();
$table->decimal('lng', 10, 8)->nullable();
```

Via an API endpoint I find the latitude and longitude.

The API returns this:

```
$geo->lat = 46.0081326;
$geo->lng = 8.9761892;
```

BUT when setting my model field like so

```
$estate->lat = $geo->lat;
$estate->lng = $geo->lng;
```

in the DB the fields gets set to `46.00000000` and `8.00000000`.

Because of this I tried setting the cast in the model like so

```
protected $casts = ['lat' => 'double', 'lng' => 'double'];
```

I also tried casting to specific decimal

```
protected $casts = ['lat' => 'decimal:8', 'lng' => 'decimal:8'];
```

But no luck. I still get `46.00000000` and `8.00000000` inside the DB.

I also tried removing Laravel `casts` and forcing the type like this

```
$estate->lat = (double) $geo->lat;
```

But I still get empty decimal points.

These are 2 new brand new columns but I tried checking if the App has some `setLatAttribute()` mutator but it does not.

Comment: So `$geo->lat == 42.9856226` but when you set `$estate->lat` to `$geo->lat` the digits after the decimal get turned to 0s?

Comment: @CalebAnthony exactly 

Comment: Which model has the `$casts` variable (did you know it has an "s" at the end)? The Estate model?

Comment: I also noticed your database stores the values as decimal, why not cast the variable as a decimal as well? In changing data types it might be breaking. Lat/Lng are generally better to be used as decimals in PHP anyway.

Comment: @CalebAnthony yes Estate model. Casts with an s, was a typo in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your database is holding the data type as a decimal (which is good!), but your application tries to read that decimal as a float.

You should be able to tell your application to continue reading the data as a decimal:

```php
protected $casts = ['lat' => 'decimal:8'];
```

If you're relying on Laravel's `$casts` functionality, you shouldn't be forcing type anywhere else in your code, this can get you into all sorts of nasty problems that are incredibly hard to debug.

Comment: Same problem... I have another project which worked fine and did not use casts nor typing and just worked. I took the same migration and for some reason I don't know it fails ini placing decimals. Same machine, same DB... :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to the casting or typing but rather to the wrong class name.

I forgot to rename the Class name into the correct one (`SmootherCommand` in `SmootherCommand.php`) and this caused misbehaviour.